# Customers are not receiving the order confirmation emails, but other email functionalities on the site seem to be working fine

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, html-email

WooCommerce Version: 8.4.0
WordPress Version: 6.4.2
PHP Version: 8.0.30
Parent Theme: Avada
Child Theme: Avada-child

The issue is as follows:

The order mail functionality is not working. We have checked the configuration of the SMTP and tested the mail; it is working fine. However, other forms on the site, such as Contact Form 7 forms, are functioning correctly.

There is an option in WooCommerce Email. When I set the Email Type to plain text, the order emails work fine.

However, when I set the option to HTML

[image]

the emails are not being received in the mailbox, even though the mail log shows them as successfully sent.

The problem occurs only when the Email Type is set to HTML.

Could someone kindly provide guidance on how to fix and debug this issue?

I have debug all the possibilities

- disable all the plugin and check for plugin conflict
- updated the child theme Woocommerce Template
- update all the plugins and also themes

Comment: Nobody could give you a useful guidance for that issue, as WooCommerce HTML emails work… In your case, there is certainly something that is making trouble: it could be some custom code added by you, a 3rd party plugin, your theme or your hosting…

Comment: Maybe your problem is deliverability. Things to try. 1. Enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG, then do the things that generate these emails, then look at wp_content/debug.log  Some SMTP servers may be refusing your emails. 2. Check recipient spam traps. 3. Use an email service provider, like sendgrid.com, that manages SPF and DKIM authentication. Good email service providers have decent logging and troubleshooting support.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, I see this notice at the bottom "This template has been overridden by your theme and can be found in: Avada-Child-Theme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php"

This means that you're customizing the HTML template and doing something wrong in that template hence the issue. You may want to remove the custom HTML template of email from your child theme and check this again.

Or simply activate parent theme for testing purpose and see if the order email arrives, if it does then definitely its your child theme customization issue and you may want to review it.

Thanks